# Pound symbol not showing in HTML with XSLT2

Tags: html, encoding, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm trying to display the pound symbol from an XML `(currencySymbol="£")`.

I'm using XSLT 2 with the encoding in the file `<xsl:output  encoding="ISO-8859-15"/>` and its showing me a `�` instead.

I've tried different approaches, using `UTF-8`, declaring the `ENTITY` inside `DOCTYPE` but still no luck. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: The pound symbol (£) and the euro (€) are -- I believe -- different things. Which one are you trying to display?

Comment: Sorry James. I was thinking about euro when writing the description. I am trying to display the pound symbol (£).

Comment: So which tool do you use to look at the transformation result?

Comment: We have developed something(in Java) in our app (at the firm) that allows us to see the HTML. It takes the XSL file the XML file and then it transforms it into HTML.

Comment: That is a rather vague description, do you use XSLT to create an HTML file and then load that into a Java Swing or AWT component to render the HTML? Or do you load the HTML file in a browser like Chrome or Edge or Firefox?

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. We load the HTML file in a browser. I used Chrome.

Comment: Consider to show us minimal but complete code samples of XML input, XSLT code, HTML the XSLT creates together with the Java code that uses Saxon to create the HTML, then I am sure we can tell what goes wrong. But without any minimal but complete details to allow us to reproduce the problem it is not possible to tell what you need to change in your XSLT or your Java code or both.

Comment: In general, if you use Saxon to create HTML output and you want to make sure the `xsl:output encoding` directive is used to create an HTML meta or charset indicating the encoding in the generated HTML then Saxon needs to be in charge of creating the result file and the output method needs to be `html` for HTML 4 or 5 or `xhtml` for XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

When I run the query

```
net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:"<a>£</a>" -o:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/pound.xml !encoding=iso-8859-15
```

I get a file whose hex content is

```
0000: 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 22 31   <?xml version="1
0010: 2E 30 22 20 65 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3D 22 69 73   .0" encoding="is
0020: 6F 2D 38 38 35 39 2D 31 35 22 3F 3E 3C 61 3E A3   o-8859-15"?><a>£
0030: 3C 2F 61 3E                                       </a>
```

That is, the "£" sign is correctly encoded as xA3.

If I now change it to HTML with the query options

```
-qs:"<html><head/><body><a>£</a></body></html>" -o:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/pound.xml !encoding=iso-8859-15 !method=html
```

The hex output is

```
0000: 3C 68 74 6D 6C 3E 0A 20 20 20 3C 68 65 61 64 3E   <html>¿   <head>
0010: 0A 20 20 20 20 20 20 3C 6D 65 74 61 20 68 74 74   ¿      <meta htt
0020: 70 2D 65 71 75 69 76 3D 22 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74   p-equiv="Content
0030: 2D 54 79 70 65 22 20 63 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 3D 22   -Type" content="
0040: 74 65 78 74 2F 68 74 6D 6C 3B 20 63 68 61 72 73   text/html; chars
0050: 65 74 3D 69 73 6F 2D 38 38 35 39 2D 31 35 22 3E   et=iso-8859-15">
0060: 0A 20 20 20 3C 2F 68 65 61 64 3E 0A 20 20 20 3C   ¿   </head>¿   <
0070: 62 6F 64 79 3E 3C 61 3E A3 3C 2F 61 3E 3C 2F 62   body><a>£</a></b
0080: 6F 64 79 3E 0A 3C 2F 68 74 6D 6C 3E               ody>¿</html>
```

which is again correct.

So I think that if this HTML is not displaying correctly, the problem is not on the XSLT side but rather on the display side. So the question is, how are you viewing the file?

iso-8859-15 is a rather unusual choice of encoding, and utf-8 would be much more normal these days. If neither is displaying correctly for you, then I think we need to know:

(a) what software are you using to display the file

(b) if this is a browser, then
   (i) which browser
   (ii) what is the media-type (content-type) in the HTTP header used when the file is retrieved from the server?